Trying to automate log collection in QXDM but cannot find the device
I am trying to automate log collection in QXDM for a modem. I am not able to get the arguments for the method ConnectToDevice:
qxdm = win32com.client.Dispatch("QXDM.QXDM5AutoApplication")
automation_window2 = qxdm.GetAutomationWindow2()
automation_window2.ConnectToDevice(?,?,?)

help command has returned the following output:
ConnectToDevice(p_deviceHandle=<PyOleMissing object at 0x000001A7D46528A0>, p_protHandle=<PyOleMissing object at 0x000001A7D46528A0>, p_bIsGpsDevice=<PyOleMissing object at 0x000001A7D46528A0>) method of win32com.client.CDispatch instance

